# Network Manager Access Point WPS Pin Disable

Tags: raspberry-pi, networkmanager, nmcli, wps

we are opening an Access Point with network manager (on a RPI4 with Raspbian) and everything is working fine except that when connecting from Windows 10 we are asked for a pin first (probably wps pin) instead of getting shown directly the passphrase field to enter. This is not observed on Mac and Linux.

Our wifi-ap configuration:

```
sudo nmcli c add con-name wifi-ap type wifi ssid test ifname wlan0 save yes autoconnect yes 802-11-wireless.mode ap 802-11-wireless.band bg ipv4.method shared wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk wifi-sec.psk "test1234"
```

We already tried multiple configurations from the provided page: https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/settings-802-11-wireless-security.html like:

- wps-method 1
- proto rsn
- pairwise ccmp

But nothing really helped. Would be fantastic to get your support here.

Thanks

Comment: Any Idea? What is the best way to disable wps with network manager?

Comment: Meet a similar issue here. Is there anyone can provide a suggestion?

Comment: As per my understanding, NetworkManager calls wpa_supplicant on it. As per my situation, wpa_supplicant find a parameter "WPS-PBC-ACTIVE" during the AP initialize.